# Placeholder scaling issue with URLImage in landscape mode

Tags: java, codenameone

I scaled the placeholder to the screen size as below. But if it is first viewed in portrait mode, it just takes the screen and doesn't cover whole screen in landscape mode. If it is 1st viewed in landscape mode, then it appears bigger than the screen size in portrait mode.

How do I fix this problem. I checked in [PropertyCross](https://www.codenameone.com/demos-PropertyCross.html) demo and the same issue exists there too.

```
private EncodedImage largePlaceholder;

protected void initVars(Resources res) {
    Image tmp = Image.createImage(Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth(), Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth() / 6 * 3, 0);
    largePlaceholder = EncodedImage.createFromImage(tmp, false);
}

findMainImg(f).setIcon(URLImage.createToStorage(largePlaceholder, getMainImg + "_0_ y", getMainImg, URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE_TO_FILL));
```

Updated:

```
int sizethumb = 0;
int sizethumb1 = 0;
if (responsesImg.size() > 0) {

    sizethumb = largePlaceholder.getWidth();
    sizethumb1 = largePlaceholder.getHeight();
    findMainImg().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(sizethumb, sizethumb1));

    findMainImg(f).getAllStyles().setBgImage(URLImage.createToStorage(largePlaceholder, newsImgFilename + "_0_ y", responsesImg.get(0).get("image_url"), URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE));

    mainImageImgViewer = findMainImg(f).getAllStyles().getBgImage();
    System.out.println("beck0 " + mainImageImgViewer); //it gives null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest setting it as the bg image of the style and setting the background behavior to `SCALE_TO_FILL` or `SCALE_TO_FIT`.

Comment: thanks it works... but i have one more issue here. i set the bgImage and when i want to retrieve bgImage(ie getBgImage) it gives null. Is that a bug? i updated what i have done in the question above

Comment: Did you call setUIID or something similar in the interim?

Comment: Did someone else call one of those API's in the interim. You can derive the component override setUIID and place a breakpoint on the super call to discover if this is happening...

Comment: hi, i didnt quite get it? how to do that?

Comment: On the component where the image disappeared just override the setUIID() method and place a breakpoint there to catch the caller to that method.

Comment: i jst change the uiid of theme (ie. background type to image scale to fit) and the problem was solved. Before it was set as gradient.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the screen size to generate your placeholder image and the width of the screen in Landscape is bigger than Portrait.

If you want to make the image responsive, you will have to add orientation  change listener which will download another image with a different size for landscape if you're coming from portrait and vice-versa.

```
private EncodedImage largePlaceholderPortrait;
private EncodedImage largePlaceholderLandscape;
private boolean isPortrait = Display.getInstance().isPortrait();

protected void initVars(Resources res) {
    Image tmp = Image.createImage(Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth(), Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth() / 6 * 3, 0);
    Image tmp2 = Image.createImage(Display.getInstance().getDisplayHeight(), Display.getInstance().getDisplayHeight() / 6 * 3, 0);
    largePlaceholderPortrait = EncodedImage.createFromImage(isPortrait ? tmp : tmp2, false);
    largePlaceholderLandscape = EncodedImage.createFromImage(isPortrait ? tmp2 : tmp, false);
}

findMainImg(f).setIcon(URLImage.createToStorage(largePlaceholderPortrait,  isPortrait ? getMainImg + "_0_y_portrait" : getMainImg + "_0_y_landscape", getMainImg, URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE_TO_FILL));


f.addOrientationListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        findMainImg(f).setIcon(URLImage.createToStorage(largePlaceholderPortrait,  isPortrait ? getMainImg + "_0_y_portrait" : getMainImg + "_0_y_landscape", getMainImg, URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE_TO_FILL));
    }
});

//Java 8
f.addOrientationListener((evt) -> {
    findMainImg(f).setIcon(URLImage.createToStorage(largePlaceholderPortrait,  isPortrait ? getMainImg + "_0_y_portrait" : getMainImg + "_0_y_landscape", getMainImg, URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE_TO_FILL));
});
```

Comment: THANKS diamond it works but i would prefer if i dont have to use 2 images for a single placeholder.